# Arduino - Select header for DHT Sensor Based on Chip (ESP32 vs ESP8266)

Tags: arduino, libraries, arduino-esp8266, esp32

I'll start by saying I'm not a C++/Arduino expert but I've played enough with this issue and googled enough where I can't figure it out.

I have some Arduino code that is calling a sensor library file which then is calling the DHT library (https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/).  There are two main versions of this library, one in DHTStable which maintains compatibility with AVR and ARM based chips and one in DHTLib which is optimized for AVR.  I am compiling the same sketch for both a ESP8266 (which requires the DHTStable) and a ESP32 (which works better with the DHTlib).

Right now I compile and download to a ESP32 then when I'm done I move the DHTLib library out, copy the DHTStable in, then compile and download for the ESP8266.  Few days or a week later I do this copying and pasting again.

In my sensor library I am already doing a check for the ESP32 for certain commands and if not a ESP32 I do the commands for a ESP8266 using `#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32)` and this works great for commands.  However I am trying to use it for the defines and it "kinda" works.  I have to take one of the two libraries and rename the header and cpp file along with all references internally to be different then the other.  Then in my If I can do a if ESP32 use dht-avr.h (renamed) else dht.h (original).

This all works but I'm using git to clone and keep updated the libraries so each time there is a update I have to go through and rename everything.  So I tried #include `<DHTlib\dht.h>` and `<DHTStable\dht.h>` but these don't work (can't find library).

Is what I want to do, calling the actual include path or two different headers when they are named identical, possible?  Since the If statement works I'm 90% there (100% if I keep renaming everything) but I'd really like this to be automatic.

@BMelis put me on the right track with the .. in the path.  The final code ended up being:

```
#ifdef ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32
#include "..\DHTlib\DHT.h"
#else
#include "..\DHTStable\DHT.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to hardcode the path to the libraries in your code. You'll have to use quotation marks for the include instead of `<...>`:

```
#ifdef ESP8266
#include "../path/to/esp8266-header.h"
#endif
#ifdef ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32
#include "../path/to/esp32-header.h"
#endif
```

Comment: I was sooooo close, just missed the .. for the sub directory above.  Marking as answer and editing first post since comments won't let me add formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library: https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library
I use in some projects and works very well